# Laravel vue components not showing up

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6

Hey so i'm trying out laravel and when i create a new project and run it i cant see any of the components i create myself. The example component shows up but when i make any changes it doesn't show up.

I created the projected using the installation guide on th laravel website. Is there something else i need to do to enable the use of vue.

Comment: Before this gets closed, you probably aren't running `npm run watch` - everytime you make a change to your javascript files, they need to recompile. You'll need to reload the web page manually each time (unless you get comfortable enough to use `npm run hot`). If that isn't doing it, then your problem is most likely the cache. Open dev tools (chrome) -> Network -> Disable Cache (check it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code

```html
//you install library vue to laravel
npm install && npm install vue-router

//after install, you can run 
npm run watch
```

You can see https://hoanguyenit.com/create-template-vuejs-and-laravel-5-4.html